# Django: multiple user using the same View and template

Tags: python, django, web-services, django-views

I have a view to send an XML request get the response and render the response in a template. But now I have a problem when two users make a request to different web services the data in the template show the data of the last request.

I don't know how to handle when multiple user make request to different web services or the same web service.

I was thinking to dynamically generate a template for every user, but I don't know how to handle the urls.

My view:

```
def LeerXMLResponseView(request):
    archivo_request = request.GET.get('xml')
    ws_service = request.GET.get('servicio')
    archivo = '/DjangoProjects/xmlcbs/media/'+ archivo_request
    with open(archivo,"r") as file:
         request_data = file.read()

    target_url = "http://1.1.1.1:1111/services/" + ws_service + "?wsdl"
    headers = {'Content-type':'text/xml'}
    data_response = requests.post(target_url, data=request_data, headers=headers).text
    jdato = xmltodict.parse(data_response)
    data = json2html.convert(json = jdato)
    data_template = data

    return render_to_response('prueba.html', {'data':data_template})
```

This view works fine for one user at time but when two or more users make a request the data is overwritten.

Any idea how to handle multiple users using the same view with different request and response?

Comment: Is there user-specific data in the archivo file? If so, what, and what is writing that file?

Comment: Yes, every user will request diferent info based in different arguments. Example: user1 will request data form the client #123, the user2 will request data from the client # 3456 or a different web services.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. In this code, you're reading a file from disk and sending its contents in the request to the external API. Is that file supposed to be per-user? If so how is it being written? Apart from the file, there isn't anything in this code that would cause interference between users.

Comment: Yes, is a file per user and per web service. I have a view to read some xml files to render a form with all needed arguments to make a request to the web service selected for the user. with the POST data of the form I create a new xml file that I will use to make the request. The users only share the same view to make the request and render the response in the template as a html table

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to store the parameters for the request in a local file. Especially as the way you have done it there can only ever be one version of this file; subsequent users will overwrite the file from the previous one.

Instead, store the necessary data in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: I know, I am some troubles sending the request to the web services, The application use around of 25 to 30 web services and every web services with at least 10 methods. I am not familiar with Django sesions, but I will read and try if your approach works for me. Thanks